# Specify script to run with SSH upon login

Tags: ssh, bash

I would like to know if there is a way to specify what script to run (on the remote machine) at login.  I'm logging into a Debian box with key-pair authentiation (no password needed).  The script needed to run will be different, so I don't want to put it into ~/.bashrc, I want to specify it on the command line when I login, something like:

`ssh username@ip script_on_remote.sh`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is pretty much how you'd do it. You can specify the script using it's full path if it's not accessible on the $PATH.

```
# if scripts on the $PATH
ssh username@ip script_on_remote.sh

# if it's not on the path
ssh username@ip /path/to/my/script_on_remote.sh

# if it's including spaces
ssh username@ip "/path to my/script_on_remote.sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the command on the command line will work. You may have to put in the full path of the command.